# array conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript.

I have the following 1-d arrays:

```
    m=[1,2,3,4]
    n=[5,6,7,8]
```

I want to convert the following in JavaScript:

```
    x=[[1,5], [2,6], [3,7], [4,8]]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am new to java-script

Comment: So loop over one and build up a new array referencing the second.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I appreciate that you're new, but the requirement here is that you show your work. You have to actually try to solve what you're doing instead of simply asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO; to avoid downvotes in the future please read the following guide [mre]

Comment: You can just run a loop and create another array with values at index from first and seconds array.

   `const m = [1, 2, 3, 4];`
    `const n = [5, 6, 7, 8];`

   `let reultArray = [];`
    `for (var i = 0; i < m.length && i < n.length; i++)`
      `reultArray[i] = [m[i], n[i]];`

   `console.log(reultArray);`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array where the callback takes the item being processed as param 1, and its index as param 2.

```js
const m = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const n = [5, 6, 7, 8]


const o = [...m].map((itm, idx) => [itm, n[idx]])

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiDimension(m, n) {
  var x = [];

  m.forEach(function(v, k) {
    x.push([m[k],n[k]]);
  });

  return x;
}

multiDimension([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]);
```